# Border on label when using transparency key

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform (with a transparency key) to make it transparent. But when I add a label, I get this "fushia" border around the label. I am aware this is because of there is no "set" background for the control. But is there a way to remove this "border".

The Form is set to background Fuchsia (transparency key Fuchsia) and the label is set to transparent. Tried painting it to a panel with the same results.

What am I missing?

How it looks, http://oi62.tinypic.com/2wq9z7c.jpg

```
public class CLabel : Label
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams { get { CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams; parms.ExStyle |= 0x20; return parms; } }

    public CLabel()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, false);
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // null
    }

     GraphicsPath GetStringPath(RectangleF rect, StringFormat format)
    {
        GraphicsPath Path = new GraphicsPath();

        Path.AddString(this.Text, this.Font.FontFamily, (int)Font.Style, this.Font.Size, rect, format);
        return Path;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        RectangleF rect = this.ClientRectangle;
        Font font = this.Font;
        StringFormat format = StringFormat.GenericDefault;

        using (GraphicsPath path = GetStringPath(rect, format))
        {
            SmoothingMode sm = e.Graphics.SmoothingMode;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            e.Graphics.FillPath(b, path);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);

            b.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public partial class Dy : Form
{
  protected override CreateParams CreateParams { get { CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams; cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; cp.ExStyle |= 0x80; return cp; } }

    public Dy()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

        // Here I add the label
        CLabel p = new CLabel{ 
            Location = new Point(768, 702),
            Text = "25",
            AutoSize = false, 
            Size = new Size(50,50), 
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, 
            BackColor = Color.Transparent, 
            ForeColor = Color.White, 
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None, 
            Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 30, FontStyle.Bold)
        };
 }
}
```

Comment: I assume this is a Windows Forms application. You shouldn't make us assume. You should add the [WinForms] tag instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like anti-aliasing artefacts.

You can try to change

```
e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

to

```
e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;
```

or you can set anti-aliasing completely off:

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
```

**Edit:** I have moved this out of the comments, as it may help some folks:

Here is a little **extra on AA-artefacts**..

AA will always create pixels that interpolate and this will always result in pixels that somewhat miss the transparency key color.

Obviously they only go away if no AA is used; but if one really needs some smoothing this little trick may help to improve the result:

Usually `TransparencyKey` is accomplished with a crass color like `Fuchsia` or `HotPink`. These are rarely used, so they're not likely to cut holes, but when they shine through a semitransparent AA pixel they are obnoxious. If you **use a less irritating color** this effect can get unobtrusive.

You just need to make sure that you are not using it elsewhere. Pick a color by `Color.FromArgb(255, r,g,b)` picking 3 unique values which you won't use elsewhere but which blend in with both foreground and more important with the background. Very low saturation and depending on your graphics, medium brightness will probably help..

`Black` or a neutral gray are not good choices even if they blend well, because they are used so often. But picking e.g. something almost black like ARGB(255, 7, 11, 5) has a good chance to blend as well without being used in the graphics and cutting holes in the output.

The best result are when you can use somthing close to the background color. If you can't forsee it this trick will more often than not fail, though..

Comment: Good. Curious: Did the TextRenderingHint suffice or did you have to set the SmoothingMode? Also: If you're happy, please accept the answer!

Comment: Yeah it was enough to just change TextRendering.

But I stumbled upon an other problem, when trying to add a border to the label. As soon as I disable AA it works , but as soon as I turn it on again I get this background again. 

Not sure if you know how to fix that without suffering the really bad quality when turning AA off.
* Updated with the current code

Comment: AA will always create pixels that interpolate. This will always result in pixels that somewhat miss the traparency key color. No way around that I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah ok. Is there a way to get around it? Make it a bitmap or maybe use OpenGL?

Tried to mark it as accepted, but it keeps reversing back.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help :)
Just tried with black and it works as indented (but I need to find a better color). I'll try and put this one as solved, but never experienced this "bug" before:P

Comment: You may want to have a look at the folks [wondering](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261599/accept-keeps-reverting?noredirect=1#comment48636_261599) what's up..

Comment: Ofc I didn't double click. Got it working now when trying with IE instead of Chrome. Wierd..